# Insert won't work

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to insert a row from a table to another table (both on the same server). The update part works perfectly, but the insert part will insert all the fields correctly but the "reponse" one. I don't understand why ...

```
<?php
        $reponse = $_POST['reponse'];
        $id = $donnees['id'];

        // Update
        $req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE table_commentaires SET reponse=? WHERE id=?');
        $req->execute(array($reponse, $id));

        $req->closeCursor();

        // Transfer
        $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO table_reponses (id_question, question, reponse, pseudo, date_publication) SELECT id, comm, reponse, pseudo, date_publication FROM table_commentaires WHERE id=?');
        $req->execute(array($id));

        // TODO: Delete from table_commentaires

        $req->closeCursor();
    ?>
```

Comment: In what way does it not insert `reponse` correctly? Is it null or garbled? What's the datatype of each `reponse` column, and what's the value of `reponse` in the relevant row of `table_commentaires`?

Comment: I'd run just `SELECT id, comm, reponse, pseudo, date_publication FROM table_commentaires WHERE id=?` and print out the values to make sure it is what you want.  Then make sure the data type of reponse matches from table_commentaires to table_reponses.

Comment: Why is this tagged with JavaScript? I removed it, makes no sense.

Comment: Both columns are TEXT. When I say it does not insert, I mean the "reponse" field of the second table is null. The value of reponse in table_commentaires is a string, any string. @SimonMᶜKenzie

Comment: When I go on phpMyAdmin and open my table the values in my table_commentaires are perfectly correct. And yes the data type are the same! @Devon

Comment: Where is the  ' $req->bind_param' ?

Comment: @mdemir You don't need bind_param if you include the parameters as an array in execute() for PDO.

Comment: As @Simon said at the top of the comments, it's much harder for us without some sort of error message or details of what happens/doesn't happen. For what it's worth I would check the target table doesn't already contain the PK values and there aren't nulls going into `not null` columns etc.